# Problema en el manejo de la clase Scanner y de la clase JOptionPane

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Hola buenas tengo un problema con estas dos clases ya que quiero pedir la opción del menú por consola y que después en el método me salte una ventana para introducir el dato que quiero buscar en la base de datos.
¿Es posible que la clase Scanner y la clase JOptionPane no pueden usarse al mismo tiempo?
Adjunto mi código:
Menú:

```
public static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hola");
        try {
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/plantillaexamen", "root", "");
            System.out.println("conexión establecida");
            
            String opcion = "";
            //String opt = "";
            do {
                //opt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca una opción (Opción 6 para finalizar)");
                System.out.print("Introduzca una opción (Opción 6 para finalizar): ");
                opcion = teclado.nextLine();
                switch (opcion) {
                    case "1":
                        System.out.println("Has elegido la opción 1");
                        leerTxtEscribirXML();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("Has elegido la opción 2");
                        leerXMLEscribirTxt();
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.out.println("Has elegido la opción 3");
                        //insertoDato(conexion);
                        //actualizoDato(conexion);
                        borrarDato(conexion);
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        System.out.println("Has elegido la opción 4");
                        listadoProfesoresEspecialidad(conexion);
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        System.out.println("Has elegido la opción 5");
                        buscaAsignatura(conexion);
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        System.out.println("FIN");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Opción incorrecta");
                }
            }while(!opcion.equals("6"));
            
            conexion.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Método para buscar en la base de datos:

```
public static void buscaAsignatura(Connection conexion) {
        try {
            Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
            
            String codigoAsignatura = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el código de la asignatura");
            
            String sql = "SELECT a.cod_asig, a.nombre_asi, ap.cod_prof, p.nombre_ape, c.cod_centro, c.nom_centro\n" +
                            "FROM c1_asignaturas a JOIN c1_asigprof ap\n" +
                            "ON(a.cod_asig = ap.cod_asig)\n" +
                            "JOIN c1_profesores p \n" +
                            "ON(ap.cod_prof = p.cod_prof)\n" +
                            "JOIN c1_centros c\n" +
                            "ON(p.cod_centro = c.cod_centro)\n" +
                            "WHERE a.cod_asig = '" + codigoAsignatura+ "'";
            
            ResultSet resul = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);
            
            System.out.printf("%s %15s %20s %20s %30s %20s\n", "CÓD ASIG", "NOMBRE ASIG", "COD PROF", 
                    "NOMBRE PROF", "COD CENTRO", "NOM CENTRO");
            while(resul.next()) {
                System.out.printf("%-15s %-21s %-14d %-35s %-18d %s\n", resul.getString(1), resul.getString(2), resul.getInt(3), 
                        resul.getString(4), resul.getInt(5), resul.getString(6));
            }
            
            resul.close();
            sentencia.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

El problema es que nunca me salta la ventana diciéndome que introduzca el código de la asignatura por lo que el programa se ejecuta de forma infinita.
Gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Comment: Probablemente se te haya quedado detrás de la ventana, prueba a minimizar. Es un bug de netbeans.

Comment: Si nada más empezar el main pongo un JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hola) si que funciona, pero si no no me salta la ventana del método

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, es cierto que la ventana se queda ejecutándose detrás del programa.